# GWT WARNING: No file found for: /com.mycompany.project.ImageViewer/GreetingService

Tags: java, gwt

Don't connect to the server... it's a project in last gwt eclipse

on click to button in gwt:

```
greetServer(textToServer,
                        new AsyncCallback<String>() {
                            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                                // Show the RPC error message to the user
                                dialogBox
                                        .setText("Remote Procedure Call - Failure");
                                serverResponseLabel
                                        .addStyleName("serverResponseLabelError");
                                serverResponseLabel.setHTML(SERVER_ERROR);
                                dialogBox.center();
                                closeButton.setFocus(true);
                            }

                            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                                dialogBox.setText("Remote Procedure Call");
                                serverResponseLabel
                                        .removeStyleName("serverResponseLabelError");
                                serverResponseLabel.setHTML(result);
                                dialogBox.center();
                                closeButton.setFocus(true);
                            }
                        });
```

my gwt server:

```
    public String greetServer(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // Verify that the input is valid. 
        if (!FieldVerifier.isValidName(input)) {
            // If the input is not valid, throw an IllegalArgumentException back to
            // the client.
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Name must be at least 4 characters long");
        }

        String serverInfo = getServletContext().getServerInfo();
        String userAgent = getThreadLocalRequest().getHeader("User-Agent");

        // Escape data from the client to avoid cross-site script vulnerabilities.
        input = escapeHtml(input);
        userAgent = escapeHtml(userAgent);

        return "Hello, " + input + "!<br><br>I am running " + serverInfo
                + ".<br><br>It looks like you are using:<br>" + userAgent;
    }
```

it's my gwt servise:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet")
public interface GreetingService extends RemoteService {
    String greetServer(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

gwt serviseAsyn file:

```
public interface GreetingServiceAsync {
    void greetServer(String input, AsyncCallback<String> callback)
            throws IllegalArgumentException;
}


web xml

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>kill.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello123/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Hello123.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

on click button - the server does not return value, because don't find file - why?

```
Jun 27, 2012 11:12:13 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /com.mycompany.project.ImageViewer/GreetingService
```

what to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `web.xml` file you map the service as `/hello123/greet`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello123/greet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

while the error shows it is trying to load the default of `/modulename/serviceinterfacename`, or /`com.mycompany.project.ImageViewer/GreetingService`. Two options are available:

1. Change the `web.xml` entry to use the default url that the RPC interface expects
2. Configure the remote service to load from your custom path

Both of theses are discussed briefly at https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication, along with other RPC setup details.

For the second option, this usually looks like this:

```
MyServiceAsync service = GWT.create(MyService.class);
((ServiceDefTarget)service).setServiceEntryPoint("/hello123/greet");
service.methodName(...
```